# PHP realpath('./models') returns "" or null?

Tags: php, realpath

When I try

```
realpath('./')
```

I get "D:\Projects\Tickle\public"

But when I try

```
realpath('./models'); // or './models/'
```

I get "" or null. why is that? The strange thing is that when I try

```
realpath('../application/models');
```

I get "D:\Projects\Tickle\application\models" which is right

**UPDATE**

My directory structure looks like below (I am using Zend Framework)

```
/application
    /models
    /controllers
    /views
    /configs
    bootstrap.php  <-- this is where I am
```

Comment: Your current dir is not `applications` one?

Comment: What is your current directory?

Comment: See update. I am in /application/bootstrap.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the output you posted, your directory structure seems to look like this:

```
D:\Projects\Tickle
    public
        foo.php
    application
        models
```

We are in `foo.php`. By using `realpath('./models');` you refer to `D:\Projects\Tickle\public\models` which does not exist.

**UPDATE**
If you want to get a file (relative to the current file), you should use something like this:

```
realpath(__DIR__ . '/models');
```

Or even better (`__FILE__` is the current file you are in):

```
realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . '/models')
```

Using the Zend Framework, the `APPLICATION_PATH` constant is defined as `realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../application')` (in `public/index.php`).

Comment: I missed the part where `realpath('./')` is public! but why? The code is actually in `/application/bootstrap.php` if you are familiar with Zend Framework. Isit because the code starts running from /public/index.php which calls bootstrap.php? using `realpath(__DIR__ . '/models')` works tho. Is `__DIR__` not same as `./`?

Comment: @jiewmeng You are in public since the file you call in the browser is the `public/index.php`. The bootstrap is just included in `public/index.php`, you are right. The difference between your two approaches is: `__DIR__` returns the directory of the current **file**. (It is a constant - different in each included file!) When you use `realpath('./')` you do not use the constant, the script takes `public/index.php` (called by the user) as starting point. Working with Zend, you should *always* use the constant `APPLICATION_PATH`, your models directory would be: `APPLICATION_PATH . '/models'`.

Answer (score 2):

Try following and see if you get `false` by any chance:

```
var_dump(realpath('./models'));
```

If I'm not mistaken, your tree structure is as shown bellow and the file you have above code in is `public`, correct? In that case, you are actually trying to get a real path of `public/models`.

```
public
    somefile.php
application
    models
```

Comment: Yes I get false. Oh and I missed the part where `realpath('./')` is public! but why? The code is actually in `/application/bootstrap.php` if you are familiar with Zend Framework. Isit because the code starts running from /public/index.php which calls bootstrap.php? using `realpath(__DIR__ . '/models')` works tho. Is `__DIR__` not same as `./`?